# Mixing row and column operations within a dplyr summarise

Tags: r, function, dplyr, summarization

The following code multiplies together two variables, `z1` and `z2`, and then sums them within groups defined by `z0`.

Is there any reasonably natural way to do both the multiplication and the `sum()` within the summation? Here `*` and `sum()` are intended to stand in for arbitrary functions intended to apply a row operation on the result of column operations, or a column operation on the result of row operations, or various weighted summary statistics based on, e.g., survey model weights, to produce a scalar summary.

```
z0 <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2))
z1 <- z2 <- 1:4
zz <- tibble(z0, z1, z2)
zz %>% group_by(z0) %>% 
    mutate(z3 = z1 * z2) %>% 
    summarise(out = sum(z3))
```

It seems to me that, although summaries are often best thought of as operations within a group on the part of a column that falls within the group, that sometimes summaries are more naturally thought of as being of two dimensional arrays, like the ratio of group means, or the groupwise `R^2` of the first variable regressed on the second. Can `summarise()` perform summaries of this sort?

Comment: `zz %>% group_by(z0) %>% summarise(out = sum(z1 * z2))` will work in this case. Do you have any examples where you need to `mutate` first and then `summarise` and it's not possible to do it within `summarise`?

Comment: Have you looked into `do` in combination with `group_by` for regression models?